# Flutter responsive navigation drawer

Tags: flutter, mobile, navigation-drawer, flutter-navigation

building responsive drawer for mobile the drawer should be open on the click of the menu button on app bar but at web version the drawer should always show the icons, on the click of any of the icon open the drawer or on hovering the icons open the drawer

Is there any way to solve it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.